# Solving Nonlinear Equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm stuck on solving this nonlinear system of equations. Assuming there is a solution, how would you solve:

$$
c_1 = x+yz
$$
$$
c_2 = y+xz
$$
$$
c_3 = z+xy
$$
Thanks!

Comment: Just posting a question without showing how you attempted to solve it generally isn't met with positive responses here.  What have you tried?

Comment: Why did you tag this as linear algebra? Also, yes, effort please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Rewriting
\begin{align}
x &= c_1-yz\tag{1}\\
y &= c_2-zx\tag{2}\\
z &= c_3-xy\tag{3}
\end{align}

Sub $(2)\to(1)$,
\begin{align}
x &= c_1-(c_2-zx)z \\
x &= c_1 - c_2z + xz^2 \\
xz^2-c_2z+(c_1-x) &= 0 \tag{4} \\
z &= \dfrac{c_2\pm\sqrt{c_2^2-4x(c_1-x)}}{2x},\qquad x\ne0
\end{align}

etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry, your system has a resultant of degree $5$**. Do you have
$$\begin{cases}x-y=\dfrac{c_1-c_2}{1-z}\\x+y=\dfrac{c_1+c_2}{1-z}\end{cases}\Rightarrow\begin{cases}x=\dfrac{c_1-c_2z}{1-z^2}\\y=\dfrac{c_2-c_1z}{1-z^2}\end{cases}$$ from which you get from your third equation
the resultant in $z$
$$\boxed{c_3(1-2z^2+z^4)=z^5-2z^3+c_1c_2z^2-(c_1+c_2)z+c_1c_2}$$

Note that for symmetry you would have a similar quintic in $x$ or $y$  if you decide to find an equation in $x$ or $y$

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Piquito's answer, considering
$$c_1 = x+yz\tag1 $$ $$c_2 = y+xz\tag2$$ $$c_3 = z+xy\tag3$$ From $(1)$, eliminate $x$ to get $$x=c_1 - y z\tag 4$$ Replace in $(2)$ and eliminate $y$
$$-c_1 z+c_2+y z^2-y=0 \implies y=\frac{c_1 z-c_2}{z^2-1}\tag 5$$ Assuming $z\neq \pm 1$, replace in $(3)$ and expand to get $$z^5-c_3
   z^4-2 z^3+ (c_1 c_2+2 c_3)z^2- \left(c_1^2+c_2^2-1\right)z+(c_1 c_2-c_3)=0\tag 6$$ which shows at least one real root in $z$.